# RegExp not working in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Everything is working fine except regular expression i have tried every solution but every time else block executes even when input is valid.

I want To use regExp to validate valid Phone Number

```
var inputValidation = function () {
this.validation = function (para1) {
    var input = $(document).find('[data-input-validation = ' + para1 + ']');
    input.each(function () {
        $(this).keyup(function(){
            var value = $(this).val();
            var validate = new inputValidation();
            validate.validater('phoneNumber',value);

        });
    });
};

this.validater = function(param1,param2) {
    switch (param1) {
        case 'phoneNumber':
            var mobileNumber = new RegExp('/[0-9-()+]{3,20}/');
            if(mobileNumber.test(param2)){
                alert('valid');
            }
            else {
                alert('false');
            }
            break;
        }
    }
};

var validate = new inputValidation();
validate.validation('search');
```

Comment: Any console errors? Can you click `<>` and create a [mcve] ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing both the *string* regex notation and the *literal regex* notation. Choose only one of:

```
new RegExp('ab+c');
new RegExp(/ab+c/);
```

in your case maybe something like this instead:

```
var mobileNumber = new RegExp(/[0-9-()+]{3,20}/);
```

Comment: can you please edit my code that will help me better

Comment: one more thing when i input special character with number it says valid. so can u help me out please

Comment: did you escape the dash?  `\-`  (i agree with Michael on this one, you should either escape dashes inside char classes, or put it first or last)

Comment: yes i did here it is RegExp(/[0-9\-()+]{3,20}/); but same i result (false as out put):p

Comment: It looks like the second '-' in the character class [] *was* actually accepted as literal and only the first occurence seems to be have been taken as a range operator. Don't know whether this is some peculiarity of the browser, but I would not rely on it to work everywhere.

Comment: what's the input that is not matching?  I noticed a space character is missing inside your character class as well  `[0-9\-\s()+]{3,20}`

Comment: suppose if i input 923432%#% it alerts valid but in actuall its not

Comment: perhaps it's matching partially...try `^[0-9\-\s()+]{3,20}$` to enforce 'whole string' matches only.

Answer (score 1):

The dash in the expression needs to be escaped. Instead of:

`/[0-9-()+]{3,20}/`

do:

`/[0-9\-()+]{3,20}/`.

As you have it, it's trying to do a range of characters from '9' to '(' which it can't understand.