# Javascript Regular Eypression not working

Tags: javascript, regex

I wrote a regex:

```
var mobileNumberRegex = new RegExp("((01)\d\d\d?)|(([+]491)\d\d\d?)|((00?49)\d\d\d\d?)");
```

I test it with this code:

```
mobileNumberInput.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
    console.log(mobileNumberRegex.test(e.target.value));
    if(mobileNumberRegex.test(e.target.value)) {
      console.log('Hurrraaa');
    } else {
      console.log('Ohjeee');
    }
  });
```

But every input returns false. (for example: 0177, +49177, 049163)

When i try this input on an online testing tool, it is working:

https://regexr.com/3v1uu

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegExp not working in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41535973/regexp-not-working-in-javascript)

Comment: Btw, your regex would be better written as `new RegExp("01\\d{2,3}|\\+491\\d{2,3}|00?49\\d{3,4}");` or `/01\d{2,3}|\+491\d{2,3}|00?49\d{3,4}/`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your request expression is inside a string literal, so the escape sequences are being consumed when the string literal is parsed into a string.

The result which is passed to the `RexExp` constructor function has `d` characters instead of `\d` digit sequences.

Use a regular expression literal instead:

```
var mobileNumberRegex = /((01)\d\d\d?)|(([+]491)\d\d\d?)|((00?49)\d\d\d\d?))/;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to declare your regex like this:

```
var mobileNumberRegex = /((01)\d\d\d?)|(([+]491)\d\d\d?)|((00?49)\d\d\d\d?)/
```

And then test it with:

```
mobileNumberRegex.test("+49177")
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay i fixed it with the following change:

```
var mobileNumberRegex = new RegExp(/((01)\d\d\d?)|(([+]49)\d\d\d\d?)|((00?49)\d\d\d\d?)/);
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try this:

```
01\d{2,3}|(\+491\d{2,3})|(0?49\d{3,4})
```

I made a few changes. The trick to regex is to keep stuff simple:

- First, I've removed all the groups (the praces) to clean stuff up. If you just test it and don't need the values of those groups returned, don't type them
- Second, I've added the curly braces, `\d\d\d?` is the same as `\d{2,3}`. The braces work like this:
  `X{4,6}` -> {min,max} -> minimal 4 X, max 6 X

There are online regex site, [on this one you can see my regex working](https://regex101.com/r/j9oUHF/1).

Answer (score -1):

You could try this:

```
mobileNumberInput.addEventListener(
    'keyup', 
     function(e) {    
        if(/(01|\+49|00?49)\d{2,4}/.test(e.target.value)) {
            console.log('Hurrraaa');
        } else {
            console.log('Ohjeee');
        }
    }
);
```

The explanation is like that:

```
(
    01        <- String starts with `01`
    |         <- OR
    \+49      <- String starts with `+49`
    |         <- OR
    00?49     <- String starts with `049` OR `0049`
)
\d{2,4}       <- and is followed with 2 to 4 digits
```

The tests I run and was all truthy was the following:

```
/(01|\+49|00?49)\d{2,4}/.test('0177');
/(01|\+49|00?49)\d{2,4}/.test('+49177');
/(01|\+49|00?49)\d{2,4}/.test('049163');
```

You could copy any of the above lines in your browser console and press enter, to see the result.

Hope this helps you :)

Comment: The one downvoted my answer could explain the reason? While the test works in the browser console I don't understand why is downvoted.

Answer (score -2):

Use this bcz your regex code is change /((01)\d\d\d?)|(([+]49)\d\d\d\d?)|((00?49)\d\d\d\d?)/